# Java, what is std?

Tags: java, netbeans, input, output, std

Hello I know this is basic but I need to code and test a solution for this question and I dont understand what std is. The senario question is below.

> A user should input 4 words from std in on seperate lines and these words should be printed out to std out

Please can someone help me how to code this in net beans?

Comment: It should be written as stdin and stdout, as in `/dev/stdin` and `/dev/stdout`.  They are the process' standard input and output, available via `System.in` and `System.out` in Java. See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdin).

Answer (score 1):

"std out" means `System.out`.
"std in" means `System.in`.
"std err" means `System.err`.

Answer (score 0):

`stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr` are the traditional names for one text input stream and two text output streams that are provided to every Unix program when it starts up.  A program is expected to read its input from `stdin` (if its command line arguments do not instruct it to read from some other source), and it is expected to write its output to `stdout`.  If the program has messages for the user that are not part of its normal output, it is expected to write those to `stderr`.

The idea of `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr` spread from Unix to MS-DOS and Linux and other operating systems.

In Java, `System.in` usually is hooked up to the `stdin` stream, `System.out` to the `stdout` stream, and `System.err` to the `stderr` stream.

Answer (score 0):

standard input (stdin)

read this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams